# Is it possible to solve a recurrence in which the biggest factor is negative (thus alternating)?

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence, recurrence-relations, order-theory, computational-complexity

Apologies if the question is ambiguous; English is not my native language. My partial solution to the problem may convey the issue more accurately: the recurrence to solve is

$$g(n) - g(n-1) - 2g(n-2) + 2g(n-3) = 0.$$

Its polynomial is thus

$$x^3 - x^2 - 2x + 2$$

and the roots I obtain are

$$(x - 1)(x - \sqrt{2})(x + \sqrt{2}).$$

With the initial conditions being

$$g(0) = 106$$
$$g(1) = 100$$
$$g(2) = 112$$

the general form is therefore

$$g(n) = 3\sqrt{2}^n + 3(-\sqrt{2})^n + 100.$$

The issue arises when I try to prove the exact order of the recurrence ($\Theta(\sqrt{2}^n)$) using the limit test. My attempt goes as such:

$$
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{3\sqrt{2}^n + 3(-\sqrt{2})^n + 100}{\sqrt{2}^n} & = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{3\sqrt{2}^n}{\sqrt{2}^n} + \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{3(-\sqrt{2})^n}{\sqrt{2}^n} + \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{100}{\sqrt{2}^n}\\
& = 3 + \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{3(-\sqrt{2})^n}{\sqrt{2}^n} + 0\\ 
& = 3 + \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{3(-\sqrt{2})^n}{\sqrt{2}^n}
\end{align*}
$$

The remaining limit diverges and I am confused at this point. I expect the explanation will be something relatively simple in retrospect and also that it will be more closely related to the notion of limits than anything else, but I nonetheless phrased my question in terms of recurrence because my uncertainty partially stems from the fact that I am now unsure whether it is possible or not to give a Big-Theta for every recurrence out there.

Thank you very much for your time and hopefully your help as well. :)

Comment: The behavior of this sequence is weird $3\cdot 2^{n/2}+3 (-1)^n 2^{n/2}+100=\{100,112,100,124,100,148,100,196,100,292,100,484,100,868,100,1636,100,3172,100,6244, \ldots\}$ increases only for **even** indices. For odd indices the values are constant $=100$. Don't know sincerely how to evaluate the asymptotic behavior. For even indices it is like $\frac13 2^{n+1}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $g$ isn’t $\Theta(f(n))$ for any $f$. This is especially clear when you write the function like this:

$$g(n)=\begin{cases}
6\cdot 2^{n/2},&\text{if }n\text{ is even}\\
100,&\text{if }n\text{ is odd:}
\end{cases}$$

this makes it clear that $g(n)$ is $O(\sqrt2^n)$ and $\Omega(1)$, and that neither estimate can be improved.

In fact if $f(n)=g(2n)$ and $h(n)=g(2n+1)$, then $f(n)$ is $\Theta(2^n)$ and $h(n)$ is $\Theta(1)$. The function $g$ restricted to even arguments grows at an entirely different rate from the function $g$ restricted to odd arguments.